# Get data from root document only in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an angular app connected to a Cloud Firestore and I am still trying to work out how to specify the rules. As of now I have the use case where a user is a kitchen (this is an app for a student dorm), which means that there can be X number of users, one for each kitchen, and I have the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      //Only allow authenticated users to read
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /kitchens/{userId}/{document=**} {
      // Only the kitchen that is logged in can write to its own data
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is that since there is a certain number of kitchens, the register screen lets the user choose which kitchen that wants to register from a dropdown list. The list is then filtered based on which kitchen id's that have not already been registered, so I need permission to read the kitchen id's. I just don't want anyone but the kitchens themselves to read the data that belongs to that kitchen. I tried with:

```
match /kitchens/{id=**} {
  // Unauthenticated users can read kitchens
  allow read: if true;
}
```

But sending a http request with Postman just gives me all that I asks for that exists under the kitchen. 
So is there a way to only be able to read the fields of the root document and not any of the collections contained in the root, so I can see which kitchens that are already registered, but not e.g. the residents of the kitchen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the rules is causing you trouble:

```
match /{document=**} {
  //Only allow authenticated users to read
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```

You might think that it's only affecting the "root" documents, but it's actually affecting **all** documents.  That `**` will match any document at any depth.  With this rule in place, any authenticated user can read every single document in the database.

You should remove this rule and replace it with one that more specifically addresses your requirements.

You have a similar problem here:

```
match /kitchens/{id=**} {
  // Unauthenticated users can read kitchens
  allow read: if true;
}
```

This allows anyone at at all to read the kitchens collection, and *all** of the nested documents in subcollections.  Again, that's how the `**` wildcard works.

If you want to restrict a match to just a single collection, don't use these "greedy" wildcards.  Just use a normal one that only matches documents in the immediate subcollection:

```
match /kitchens/{id} {
  // Unauthenticated users can read kitchens
  allow read: if true;
}
```

You might want to go over the documentation about [recursive wildcards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards).

Comment: The name of the wildcard doesn't matter. Use whatever you want.  If you have followup questions, please post those as separate questions.